# Javascript - Null Value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple calculation engine, however I'm getting a null value in the console log. For me it looks ok, and it should work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    odds();
    $("#backstake, #backodds, #layodds, #laycom").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        odds();
    });
});

function odds() {
    var backstake = document.getElementById('backstake').value;
    var backodds = document.getElementById('backodds').value;
    var layodds = document.getElementById('layodds').value;
    var laycom = document.getElementById('laycom').value;

    var result = parseInt(backstake) + parseInt(backodds);
    var laystake = parseInt(backstake) * parseInt(backodds) / (parseInt(layodds) - parseInt(laycom));
    //var laystake = parseInt(backstake) * parseInt(backodds);

    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
        document.getElementById('yourlaystake').value = laystake;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4j7vm37/246/

Comment: You have an obvious typo... `<input type="text" name="layodds" id="laysodds" />` ... `document.getElementById('layodds').value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the value of the input field with id `layodds`, but according to your jsfiddle, you only have a field with id `laysodds`:

```
var layodds = document.getElementById('layodds').value;
```

Comment: thanks, that was embarrassing

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your markup:

```
<tr><td>Lay Odds:</td><td><input type="text" name="layodds" id="laysodds" /></td></tr>
```

change it to:

```
<tr><td>Lay Odds:</td><td><input type="text" name="layodds" id="layodds" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: thanks, that was embarrassing